Fixed point of continuous function $[1,10 ]$ to $(2,8)$
Statement:
Every continuous function $f:[1,10] \to (2,8)$ has a fixed point. True/ False
I feel it is True, since image of $[1,10]$ will be a compact subset in $(2,8)$, by fixed point theorem we must have a fixed point. But I am not sure how to prove it, please help.

Statement is true. Consider $g(x) = f(x) - x$. It's continuous, $g(1) > 0 > g(10)$ hence $g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$ by intermediate value theorem. Q.e.d.
